# Prevent exsheets from creating newline at beginning of question

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, exsheets

I want to use the `exsheets` package for some homework sheets in combination with `enumitem`.
When I encapsulate an `enumerate` environment inside a `question` environment, the first item of the enumeration is shifted vertically, probably by a newline or parskip, as you can see in question no. `3` on the picture.

[image: Output]

Rather I would like it to start on the very same line.
How can I do that with exsheets?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
\SetupExSheets{headings=empty}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      fill,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      text=white,
      minimum size=1.5em
    ] (char) {\sffamily\bfseries #1};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]

\item
\begin{question} % This works as it should.
Please compute the following.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is $100+100$?
    \item Compute $100-100$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\item
\begin{enumerate} % I would like to use the 'question' environment here.
    \item What is $2+2$?
    \item Compute $2-2$.
\end{enumerate}

\item
\begin{question} % But if I directly add the enumerate-environment, see what happens :(
\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is $333+333$?
    \item Compute $999-333$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! I'd like to help but have never worked with exsheets. When I compile your example, it tells me that I'm missing a config file and the result looks different (has headings for every question). Maybe you could post you exsheets_headings.cfg file as well to make it easier to identify the problem.

Comment: @Harald, I do not have any special `exsheets_headings.cfg` file, other than the one [shipped with exsheets](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_headings.cfg). Maybe you are using an older version of exsheets? Try using `\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}`.

Comment: That's not `exsheets`' fault: list environments add some vertical space in the beginning, namely `\topsep` (+`\parskip`+`\partopsep` IIRC). (As an aside: I'd set `exsheets`' `counter-format` to use the circled numbers instead of surpressing `exsheets`' numbers completely and using an `enumerate` environment as a shell)

Comment: @cgnieder, no they don't?! In number 2) there is no vertical space added in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, they do, see page~145 of the LaTeX companion

Comment: You'll see the same spacing after number 2 if you add `\leavevmode` after the corresponding `\item`

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to prevent `exsheets`' `question` environment from leaving vertical mode...

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your help. So the solution would be to use exsheet's `counter-format`? I will look into that.

Comment: @JayStrictor no that won't help with the spacing issue

Answer (score 1):

Another (equally bad) option, if you really want to use `tasks`, e.g., for its nice horizontal layout.

```
\begin{question}
\begin{tasks}[before-skip=\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip-\parskip\relax]
    \task What is $333+333$?
    \task Compute $999-333$.
\end{tasks}
\end{question}
```

Still, I wish that inline lists was the default behavior with `runin` heading styles.

Answer (score 0):

As a very dirty walkaround I now use

```
\begin{question}
\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt]
    \item What is $333+333$?
    \item Compute $999-333$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
```

This works, but it's not very nice.