# Exsheets is going on a new line

Tags: exsheets

How do I disallow exsheets from starting a question on a new line if I have to use the enumerate environment immediately in it?

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{exsheets}
 \begin{document}
 \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
 \begin{question}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Air
 \item Water
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{question}
 \end{document}
```

I tried the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214290/prevent-exsheets-from-creating-newline-at-beginning-of-question) but it is not overwriting the first item on the words: Exercise 1.

```
\begin{question}
\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt]
\item Air
\item Water
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
```

Comment: You do know that the options to `{enumerate}` only work if you load the `enumitem` package?

Comment: @clemens: No I didn't. Thanks. But including it is still not giving the desired output.

Comment: Obviously not. You should read the `enumitem` manual about the `leftskip` option.

Comment: @clemens: If I try \setlength{\leftskip}{1in} then all the items are shifted. I need only the first item shifted.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `leftmargin` option which is described in the `enumitem` manual. The one that you set `leftmargin=*`

Comment: @clemens: This also shifts all the items.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted: it's the same in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Set `leftmargin` to a suitable value, e.g. `3.5cm`.

Also, the vertical space can be added directly into the `enumerate` options (`before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3.5cm,topsep=0pt,before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}]
\item Air
\item Water
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

I'm not sure to understand your request in the comments, but here are two possibilities:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}

\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=3.5cm,topsep=0pt,before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}]
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,resume]
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\bigskip

\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=3.5cm,topsep=0pt,before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}]
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=*,resume]
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\item Very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very very long text
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to keep the word Water directly below Exercise 1?

Answer (score 1):

To have the second (+third and so on) item under "Exercise" you can use a second `enumerate` session. Something like in one of the two examples below (I used karlkoeller's MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
\begin{question}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3.5cm,topsep=0pt,before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}]
\item Air
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,partopsep=0pt,resume]
\item Water
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=3.5cm,topsep=0pt,before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}]
        \item Air
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,partopsep=0pt,resume]
        \item Water
    \end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Edit:**
When I want to have the items flowing like any other text I simply do not use `enumerate` (or any other alike), I just do it manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\dummyText{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
\begin{question}
    1. \dummyText \\ 
    2. \dummyText
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I thought of that. The problem is that the first item is entirely shifted. If the first item consists of text which is more then one line, then the entire block of text is shifted which doesn't look nice. Is there a way to have only the first line of the first item shifted?

Comment: @Shahab In that case I'd simply not use `enumerate`- answer updated.